# Create dynamic query in ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I create a report from this query:

```
select DocumentNumber,DocumentDate, from Documents where DocumentNumber ="Feb_345"
```

But I want to have a dynamic query. I want to create a form where user will enter a Document number and after that i will save this number in string variable in my OnClick function and after that I will sent this document number to my query as parameter in where statment. So when user open the report then he will see a report for document that he enter in the form earlier.

I' ve got a problem because when I save document number in my vba script I dont know how to send this variable to query as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your query to:

```
select DocumentNumber, DocumentDate from Documents
```

and then open the report filtered for the selected document number:

```
Dim DocumentNumber As String
Dim WhereCondition As String

WhereCondition = "DocumentNumber = '" & YourSelectedDocumentNumber & "'"    
DoCmd.OpenReport NameOfYourReport, acViewNormal, , WhereCondition
```

For two or more parameters, expand the Where condition:

```
select DocumentNumber, Author, DocumentDate from Documents
```

and:

```
Dim WhereCondition As String

WhereCondition = "DocumentNumber = '" & YourSelectedDocumentNumber & "' And Author = '" & Author & "'"    
DoCmd.OpenReport NameOfYourReport, acViewNormal, , WhereCondition
```

Comment: thanks :) , and If i want to have a parameter in select fields for example   select @Name, DocumentNumber from Document? Is it posible to send select parameter from form to query?